# conditionally renaming cells based on their current value

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in the form of a .csv, snippet view below;

```
name        sub_name                    level
Food        Food                        group
Food        Fruit and vegetables        subgroup
Food        Meat, poultry and fish      subgroup
```

I want to replace every cell value in the level column with new names. If it currently says "group" I want to change that to "primary" and if it currently says "subgroup" I want to change it to "secondary"

Then I plan on creating a new duplicate df, in which I will remove any rows where the "level" is "primary" using:

```
graphexpD = expDS
graphexpD <- graphexpD %>%
   filter(!grepl("primary", level))
```

Comment: [?ifelse](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/02/if-else-and-ifelse/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this, using the [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse),

First, loading packages,

```
# install.packages(c("tidyverse"), dependencies = TRUE) 
library(tidyverse)
```

Second, creating data, (see [other examples](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/))

```
df <- tribble(
  ~name, ~sub_name,  ~level,
  "Food", "Food",  "group",
  "Food", "Fruit and vegetables",  "subgroup",
  "Food", "Meat, poultry and fish",  "subgroup")
df
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  name  sub_name               level   
  <chr> <chr>                  <chr>   
1 Food  Food                   group   
2 Food  Fruit and vegetables   subgroup
3 Food  Meat, poultry and fish subgroup
```

Third, recode using `case_when` (see [more examples](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html))

```
df <- df %>% mutate(level = case_when(
  level == "group" ~    "primary",
  level == "subgroup" ~ "secondary",
  TRUE                      ~ "other"
))
```

Forth, take a look at the recoded data,

```
df
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  name  sub_name               level    
  <chr> <chr>                  <chr>    
1 Food  Food                   primary  
2 Food  Fruit and vegetables   secondary
3 Food  Meat, poultry and fish secondary
```

Fifth, `filter()` (see [more filter options](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter.html))

```
df2 <- df %>% filter(level != "primary")

df2
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  name  sub_name               level    
  <chr> <chr>                  <chr>    
1 Food  Fruit and vegetables   secondary
2 Food  Meat, poultry and fish secondary
```

Answer (score 1):

If group and subgroup are the only values in `level` then then a simple `ifelse` line in base R could do the conversion, followed by a single base R `subset`line to return df2:

```
df1$level <- ifelse(df1$level == "group", "primary", "secondary")
df2 <- subset(df1, level != "primary")
```